# Exchange Server Failure Email Notification

Tags: exchange-server

When we receive a failure notification from Exchange server (Microsoft Outlook as client), the failure notification has a section as below:

```
Received: from ServerName (ServerIP) by ExchangeServerName
 with Microsoft SMTP Server id ; Mon, 6 Apr 2015 23:59:51 -0600
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: <Test@Test.com>
To: <SomeTest@Test.com>
CC: <TestCC@Test.com>, <TestCC2@Test.com>
Date: Tue, 7 Apr 2015 01:59:52 -0400
Subject: Test Subject
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
```

This section has two date stamps (One in the Received field and another in Date field). What do these two indicate? Also the Date Stamp in both the fields have a negative value against them (-0600 & -0400). What do these values indicate?

Any information regarding this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are time stamps that include the offset from GMT (Timezone).  -0600 is probably Mountain Daylight Time, and -0400 is probably eastern Daylight time..  The reason for the difference is the TimeZone Setting on the client and server. (And also the clocks are not synced, hence the 1 second difference).

```
Received: from ServerName (ServerIP) by ExchangeServerName
 with Microsoft SMTP Server id ; Mon, 6 Apr 2015 23:59:51 -0600
```

The above shows that it was received by the server on the Apr 6 2015 at 11:59:51PM MDT,

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: <Test@Test.com>
To: <SomeTest@Test.com>
CC: <TestCC@Test.com>, <TestCC2@Test.com>
Date: Tue, 7 Apr 2015 01:59:52 -0400
Subject: Test Subject
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
```

The above is generally set by the mail client and shows that it was sent on April 7 01:59:52 AM EDT.  These are both the same time since Eastern is 2 hours ahead of Mountain..

This can happen if say your client was in Denver CO, and your Server was in NY,NY.